# Adjust crontab from PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I have a set of [on/off] buttons in HTML where I use PHP to to react on pressed buttons. The [On] button is supposed to add a line into crontab. The [Off] button should remove all entries of a specific crontab user.

**The Problem:**

Cannot edit crontab from index.php.

**What works:**

The scripts for "add" and "remove" works if sending them directly from a terminal. Both buttons reacts and can printout the first echo-line from within each if-statement.

**Clarification of question:**

Why can't the index.php trigger the other php scripts ?

**Index.php**

```
<!-- Form  -->
<form method="post">
    <input id="button_on" type="submit" name="button_on" value="on">
    <input id="button_off" type="submit" name="button_off" value="off">
</form>

<?php

/**
 * Button logics.
 */

// Coalesce operator. If input is none, add 0.
$button_on  = $_POST["button_on"] ?? 0;
$button_off = $_POST["button_off"] ?? 0;

if(!$button_on == 0) {
    echo "Button [on] pressed!"; // Verify react on button.

    $output2 = shell_exec('php 1_add_crontab_lines.php');
    echo $output2;
}

if(!$button_off == 0) {
    echo "Button [off] pressed!"; // Verify react on button.

    $output3 = shell_exec('php 2_delete_crontab_lines.php');
   echo $output3;
}

?>

<!-- For troubleshooting. -->
<pre>

---------------------------------
Content of [$_POST]
---------------------------------
<?php print_r($_POST) ?>
```

**1_add_crontab_lines.php**

```
<?php

$cronjob = "* * * * *";

$output1 = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('crontab.txt', $output1 . $cronjob.PHP_EOL);

echo exec('crontab -u trader crontab.txt');
```

**2_delete_crontab_lines.php**

```
<?php

echo exec('crontab -r');
```

Comment: It's most likely a permission issue. If you run a PHP script through the command line, it will use your user. If you run a PHP script through a web server, it will be the web server-user that executes the script.  Usually, web server-users don't have enough permissions to edit the system (which is a good thing).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I assume your theory is strengthen by the fact that the "add/delete" php scripts can run from a terminal, but running the same scripts  directly (without index.php), from browser does not work.